# Micah 4:14 or 5:1 - why the discrepancy?

Tags: hebrew-bible, bible-versions, micah, versification

In  most translations of the Bible I have seen, it is noted that [Micah 5:1 is actually Micah 4:14 in Hebrew.](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Micah+5&version=ESV) (see note "a")

What is the cause of this discrepancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the MT there is a closed [parsha break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parashah) between the verses that are numbered in Christian editions as Micah 5:1 and 5:2. The Jews adopted the Christian chapter breaks in the printed editions of the MT except when the Christian chapter breaks split a parsha within three verses of the beginning or end of a parsha, in which case the printed MT editions move the chapter break forward a verse or two to match the parsha break. There are a number of such occurrences, for example see this post regarding the end of [Genesis 32](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/25780/17080).